# Ternary operator for Bigdecimal null validation

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, ternary-operator, bigdecimal

Why am I getting null pointer exception in this code?

```
    BigDecimal test = null;
    String data = "";
    try {
    System.out.println(test==null?"":test.toString());
    data = test==null?"":test.toString();
    System.out.println(data);
    data = data +  " " + test==null?"":test.toString(); // catching null pointer in this line
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's evaluating the expressions as:

```
data = (data +  " " + test==null)?"":test.toString();
```

so, since `data +  " " + test` is not `null`, it attempts to call `test.toString()` even when `test` is `null`.

Change

```
data = data +  " " + test==null?"":test.toString();
```

to

```
data = data +  " " + (test==null?"":test.toString());
```

Comment: i prefer to start the checking with  `null==test`
in some cases it tries to get the value first so sometimes it throws null pointer exception without checking if it isnull

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 8 there is also an alternative way to deal with potential `null` references: `Optional`

To prevent an NPE while converting a `BigDecimal` to a `String` you can use an `Optional` like that:

```
String data = Optional.ofNullable(test).map(BigDecimal::toString).orElse("");
```

This way you don't need to check `test` several times if it is `null`. Having `test` once wrapped in an `Optional` you could work on being safe, that any conversion (`map`) will be performed only if `test` is not referencing `null`.